# stop the php script if no results found in the first while statment

Tags: php

What is the best way to stop the script if there are no results????
The Upload the file that is created to a vender but I don't need to creat a file if there is no results,
I have a second question what is the best way to run this every hour between 8 am and 6 pm Monday through Friday?
I found a lot of information on this if using MySQL but we are using Microsoft SQL Server.

Thanks for the help!

```
    <?php

$connect = odbc_connect("removed");
if (!$connect) {
    exit("Connection Failed: " . $connect);
}
$gr_total = 0;
$gr_count = 0;
$sql      = "


SELECT distinct 
    ltrim(rtrim(SO.ompCustomerOrganizationID))as customer
    ,ltrim(rtrim(left(cmoName,30))) as name
    ,left(ltrim(rtrim(cmoAddressLine2)),30) as address1
    ,ltrim(rtrim(cmoCity)) as city
    ,ltrim(rtrim(cmoState)) as state
    ,ltrim(rtrim(cmoPostCode)) as postal
    , ltrim(rtrim(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(cmoPhoneNumber, '(', ''), ')', ''), '-', ''))) as phone

FROM m1_kf.dbo.SalesOrders SO
LEFT JOIN m1_kf.dbo.Organizations ON cmoOrganizationID = SO.ompCustomerOrganizationID
WHERE ompCreatedDate >='06-11-2017' and ompPaymentTermID in ('CN30','CTN30')
and UOMPSCHEDULENUMBER !=1 and ompOrderTotalBase > 1

";

$sql2   = " 
 select  
 ltrim(rtrim(ompCustomerOrganizationID)) as cust
 ,ltrim(rtrim(ompSalesOrderID)) as orderid
 , right('00000000'+cast(cast(round(ompOrderTotalBase,0)as int) as varchar(8)),8) as num
 ,REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ompRequestedShipDate, 1), '/', '') as reqship
 ,'030' as terms
 ,REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ompRequestedShipDate, 1), '/', '') as ship

 FROM m1_kf.dbo.SalesOrders SO

WHERE ompCreatedDate >='06-11-2017' and ompPaymentTermID in ('CN30','CTN30')
and UOMPSCHEDULENUMBER !=1 and ompOrderTotalBase > 1
order by SO.ompCustomerOrganizationID
 ";
$result = odbc_exec($connect, $sql);
if (!$result) {
    exit("Error in SQL");
}
    $mycount    = 0;
    $tradestyle = ' ';
    $address2   = ' ';

$my_file    = 'cit_order_upload.co';
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'w+') or die('Cannot open file:  ' . $my_file);
while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {
    $record_type = 'A';
    $cit_cust_id = '1234';
    $cust_num    = $row['customer'];
    $name    = $row['name'];
    $address = $row['address1'];
    $city    = $row['city'];
    $state   = $row['state'];
    $postal  = $row['postal'];
    $phone   = $row['phone'];

    fprintf($handle, "%-4s%-2s%-1s%-15s%-30s%-30s%-30s%-17s%-2s%-9s%-10s", $cit_cust_id, $tradestyle, $record_type, $cust_num, $name, $address, $address2, $city, $state, $postal, $phone . "\n");

    $mycount = $mycount + 1;

}

$results = odbc_exec($connect, $sql2);
if (!$results) {
    exit("Error in SQL");
}
    $mycount2 = 0;
    $space1   = ' ';
    $space6   = ' ';If the first while loop does not have any results then stop the script
    $space12  = ' ';
    $today    = date("mdy");
    echo "<table><tr>";
    echo "<th>CustID</th>";
    echo "<th>OrderId</th>";
    echo "<th>Amount</th>";
    echo "<th>TotalAmount</th>";
while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($results)) {
    $client     = '1234';
    $trade      = ' ';
    $record_ty  = 'R';
    $cust       = $row['cust'];
    $orderid    = $row['orderid'];
    $num        = $row['num'];
    $reqship    = $row['reqship'];
    $terms      = $row['terms'];
    $ship       = $row['ship'];
    $mycount2   = $mycount2 + 1;
    $gr_total   = $gr_total + $row['num'];
    $tradestyle = '99';
    $custnum    = '999999999999999';
    $record     = 'S';
    $recordtype = '999999T999999999999999';
    fprintf($handle, "%-4s%-1s%-1s%-15s%-22s%-8s%-1s%-6s%-3s%-6s", $client, $trade, $record_ty, $cust, $orderid, $num, $space1, $reqship, $terms, $ship . "\n");



    echo "<tr><td>$cust </td>";
    echo "<td> $orderid </td>";
    echo "<td>  $num </td>";
    echo "<td> $gr_total </td></tr>";
}
fprintf($handle, "%-4s%-2s%-1s%-15s%06d%06d%-6s%012d", $client, $tradestyle, $record, $custnum, $mycount, $mycount2, $space6, $gr_total);
fprintf($handle, "\n");
fprintf($handle, "%-22s%06d%06d%-6s%012d%-12s%-6s", $recordtype, $mycount, $mycount2, $space6, $gr_total, $space12, $today);
fclose($handle);

?>
```

Comment: Use `break;` if you want to just break the while loop

Comment: I only want it to stop if there are no results

Comment: @kk4iku Yep, that sounds like an if statement to me. `if(empty($result)) break;` or just don't start the loop at all if there are no results

Comment: What should happen if the first query has results but the second query does not? What should happen if the second query has results but the first query does not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have this stop condition if query is unsuccessful, for handling case with no results modify it like below:

```
if (!$result) {
    exit("Error in SQL");
}
if (0 === odbc_num_rows($result)) {
    exit("No results");
}
```

Check [the docs for OBDC_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/function.odbc-num-rows.php).

About your secondary question - [cron utility](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference) is probably the most popular way to schedule jobs. Your crontab string should be like this:

```
* 8-18/1 * * 2,3,4,5 yourscript.php
```

Comment: if (!$result) {
    exit("Error in SQL");
} it does not stop the script do I need to move the last bracket to include the rest of the script?

Comment: are you sure that it doesn't? If no results, script ends with message "Error in SQL", if some rows returned - rest of the script will be executed normally, so you don't need to move brackets

Comment: I get the below messages if no results.
Notice: Undefined variable: client in /var/www/html/dashboard/cit_order_upload.php on line 122

Notice: Undefined variable: record in /var/www/html/dashboard/cit_order_upload.php on line 122

Notice: Undefined variable: custnum in /var/www/html/dashboard/cit_order_upload.php on line 122

Notice: Undefined variable: recordtype in /var/www/html/dashboard/cit_order_upload.php on line 124

Comment: I updated the answer, check odbc_num_rows function to test results count